# Negative values over trained data using svm but 0.99 accuracy using LinearRegression

Tags: python, svm, linear-regression

I am following a tutorial for predicting stock market prices using Linear Regression. I am using the `LinearRegression` tool from `sklearn.linear_model`. After doing a fit and score using this, I got an accuracy of 0.992 over my test data.

The tutorial then goes on to use svm for the same. It uses `sklearn.svm.SVR` for this. When I fit the same training data and test it using this, I get -0.15 score and I checked in the docs, it means the model can be arbitrarily worse. Confused, I go on to score the model over the same data it was trained over and the score again is -0.15. What am I missing here? Also, the doc says "The best possible score is 1.0 and it can be negative (because the model can be arbitrarily worse).", What does "can be arbitrarily worse" signify?

I am using `quandl.get('WIKI/GOOGL')` for my data if that helps.

This is my code :

```
clf = LinearRegression()
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
clf.score(X_test, y_test) //0.9924

clf = svm.SVR()
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
clf.score(X_test, y_test) //-0.1514
```

Also, I am currently taking Andrew Ng's ML course along with this so I know about Linear Regression but I haven't reached svm till now so when this one used svm for making predictions and the predictions were way off, it confused me. So, I wanted to know if there was a particular reason why this happened.

Comment: (1) can be arbitrarily worse -> model-predictions might deviate from the target in some unbounded way -> this is reflected in that score (2) Grab some basics of ML (3) Show some code (4) Don't use SVR's default-arguments without understanding them! (kernel + C!!! these are parameters to tune)

Comment: I have made the required edits. I am still unaware of the underlying implementation of svm but i wanted to know why there was such a huge difference in the two models

Comment: Because they all take parameters which imply different assumptions about your data! LinearRegression is pretty robust, kernel-SVMs are not. No offense: but without knowing the difference between an rbf-kernel and a linear-kernel (check out the docs; rbf=default) you should be careful with your experiments!

Comment: Thank you for letting me know that. I will get back to this once I know what svm really is. :D

Comment: Do that and also try: ```clf = svm.SVR(kernel='linear')```. Also: Ng's course will 100% mention the kernel-trick leading to the rbf-kernel SVM (continue with the course).

Comment: fit is taking a really long time when I set kernel to linear. I had to `ctrl+C` out of it so couldn't test it. Thanx btw. :D